# Read in javascript a spring controller model

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I have a controller where a JSONObject is passed as parameter. I would like to work with the object "all" in javascript (client side) not in the server side (JSP) so I don't want to get the object with JSP tags.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/dfi/rca" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRcaResult(Model model, String flight_id) {
        ...
        JSONObject all = new JSONObject ();
        ...
        model.addAttribute("all",all);          
        return "dfi/rca";
    }
```

I have a JSP file that import a Javasript file where I use the attribute all but I don't know how to access to it. If I use this code in the JSP file it works properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var all= "${all}";
</script>
```

But if I try the same importing a Javascript file in the JSP, it doesn't get anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/all.js"></script>
```

In all.js:

```
var rcaresults = JSON.parse('${all}');
```

Are there any way to read the Spring model attributes in a Javascript file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is run on the client side. Your model `model.addAttribute("all",all);` does not exist on the client side, it only exists on the server side while you are rendering your .jsp.

If you want data from the model to be available to client side code (ie. javascript), you will need to store it somewhere in the rendered page. For example, you can use your Jsp to write JavaScript assigning your model to JavaScript variables.
e.g `<script>var paramOne =<c:out value="${all}"/></script>`

Comment: Thanks, finally I got the data in the JSP (server) then called a function defined in the javascript file (client) `<script type="text/javascript">var all = '${all}'; graphsData(all); </script>`

Answer (score 1):

when you use `src`, your browser (and not your backend) will try to fetch the javascript file from

```
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/all.js"
```

so the file is not processed by the server as a ModelView.